# Why is Array.prototype.some() converting the type? Is it really?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

```
var x = ["foo","bar"]
function eq2(elem) {return elem == this}
function eq3(elem) {return elem === this}

x.some(eq2, "foo") //true
x.some(eq3, "foo") //false
```

So what is happening within `x[0]` that it is not `===` to `"foo"`

Comment: because `this` is not of type `string`..

Comment: `new String('foo') !== 'foo'`

Comment: @Vohuman Indeed.  But why is it a `new String()` in the first place?

Comment: @JamesThorpe because you're type checking.

Comment: @Pogrindis No - the array is created with `"foo"`.  `"foo"` is also passed as the `thisArg` to `some()`.  There is no `new String()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the helpful answers i ended up using:

```
x.indexOf("foo") > -1 //true
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're passing `"foo"` as the [`thisArg` to `.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Parameters), it can't use an arbitrary string as `this` - it needs to be an object reference.  To do so, it automatically wraps it as an object, so your code is equivalent to:

```
var x = ["foo","bar"]
function eq2(elem) {return elem == this}
function eq3(elem) {return elem === this}

x.some(eq2, new Object("foo")) //true
x.some(eq3, new Object("foo")) //false
```

This is turning it into an object of the string representation, rather than just the raw string itself, so the comparison using types fails:

```
console.log("foo");
//foo
console.log(new Object("foo"));
//String {0: "f", 1: "o", 2: "o", length: 3, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "foo"}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [MDN on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> Note that with `call` and `apply`, if the value passed as `this` is not an object, an attempt will be made to convert it to an object using the internal `ToObject` operation.

This results in an object being compared to a primitive value, for which holds:

```
new String('foo') == 'foo' // true
```

but (as [Vohuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/vohuman) correctly pointed out):

```
new String('foo') !== 'foo' // true
```

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) however, primitive values are not autoboxed, so it works there:

```js
~function()
{
    "use strict";
    var x = ["foo", "bar"];
    function eq2(elem) {return elem == this;}
    function eq3(elem) {return elem === this;}

    document.write(x.some(eq2, "foo") + '<br>');
    document.write(x.some(eq3, "foo") + '<br>');
}();
```